# How to show "Email Confirm" Input text-box ONLY when the old email was updated?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

[image: NotGOod]
**Error !!**

---

[image: Good]
That's what I **WANT** !

---

I've been struggling trying to figure it out how to show "**Email Confirm**" Input text-box ONLY when the old email was updated?
Can anybody tell me what I missed ? :(

The view started to break when the user doesn't provide the email_again.
It's redirect back

- with old input(s)
- errors message(s)
- hide email_again label `// I don't want that`
- hide email_again input-box `// I don't want that`

I am not sure what to do now. If any part of my post wasn't clear, please leave a comment - I'll fix it. :)

---

**Here is my question :**

Can anyone suggest any strategy or solution to fix this issue ?

**JS**

- Hide #email_again if no input in #email
- Show #email_again if there is an input/change in #email

  ```
    $('#email_again_label').hide();
    $('#email_again').hide();

    $('#email').on('input', function (event) {
      var text = $(this).val();
    if (text === '') { // If email is empty
    $('#email_again').prop('disabled', true);

  } else {

    $('#email_again').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#email_again_label').show();
    $('#email_again').show();
  }
  });

  </script>
  ```

---

Comment: have you tried the change method in jquery? Something like: `$('#email').change(function() { $('#email_again').show(); });`

Comment: I'm kind of new to `JavaScript`. So am I allow to use the change function even if I don't use drop-down menu to trigger the change. Right now, I used the #email input to trigger the whole thing. Can you suggest any starter code ? Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: the `change()` function is triggered everytime the value is changed for the selected element. So the code I previously showed will trigger anytime you type into the `#email` input. Because of this you can, inside the change handler, test the value to make sure it isn't empty and then hide or show the `#email_again` input accordingly.

Comment: It seem like you knew a lot of about it. I hope you don't mind put the answer to this post. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if sarcastic... did my suggestion work?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot the word `mind`. I meant to say I hope you don't mind put the answer to this post. I tried to fix it as you suggested. I might had an improper syntax somewhere.

Comment: Did this answer end up working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [jQuery change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function you can change the visibility of your `#email_again` element based upon the value of the `#email` element. For example:

```
<script>
$('#email').change(function() {

    if($('#email').val === '') {   
        $('#email_again').hide();
    } else {
        $('#email_again').show();
    }

});
</script>
```